Ekf_node not publishing any tf transform
I am working with Nav2 packages for autonomy. A first step to make this work is to get odometry working. I am trying to get an ekf_node to publish an odom->base_footprint transform (the URDF has base_footprint at the root) using IMU data. However, for some reason it is not publishing any transform (view_frames sees no transforms whatsoever).
ros2 topic info --verbose /ouster/imu confirms that ekf node is subscribing to the topic:

Type: sensor_msgs/msg/Imu
Publisher count: 1
Node name: imu_sim
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/Imu
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.0f.e6.9b.f7.15.b4.90.00.00.00.00.00.00.11.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
Reliability: RELIABLE
History (Depth): UNKNOWN
Durability: VOLATILE
Lifespan: Infinite
Deadline: Infinite
Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
Liveliness lease duration: Infinite
Subscription count: 1
Node name: ekf_filter_node
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/Imu
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.0f.e6.9b.f5.15.50.38.00.00.00.00.00.00.21.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
Reliability: BEST_EFFORT
History (Depth): UNKNOWN
Durability: VOLATILE
Lifespan: Infinite
Deadline: Infinite
Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Here is my launch file:
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os
from launch_ros.descriptions import ComposableNode, ParameterFile
from nav2_common.launch import RewrittenYaml
from launch.actions import SetEnvironmentVariable

def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='beep_autonomy').find('beep_autonomy')

    robot_localization_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
       package='robot_localization',
       executable='ekf_node',
       name='ekf_filter_node',
       output='screen',
       parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/test-ekf.yaml'), {'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')}]
    )

    imu_sim = launch_ros.actions.Node(
       package='arm_ik',
       executable='imu_sim',
       name='imu_sim',
       output='screen'
    )


    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='use_sim_time', default_value='True',
                                    description='Flag to enable use_sim_time'),
        robot_localization_node,
        imu_sim
    ])

Here is my YAML file:
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:
# The frequency, in Hz, at which the filter will output a position estimate. Note that the filter will not begin
# computation until it receives at least one message from one of theinputs. It will then run continuously at the
# frequency specified here, regardless of whether it receives more measurements. Defaults to 30 if unspecified.
        frequency: 30.0

# ekf_localization_node and ukf_localization_node both use a 3D omnidirectional motion model. If this parameter is
# set to true, no 3D information will be used in your state estimate. Use this if you are operating in a planar
# environment and want to ignore the effect of small variations in the ground plane that might otherwise be detected
# by, for example, an IMU. Defaults to false if unspecified.
        two_d_mode: true

# Whether to publish the acceleration state. Defaults to false if unspecified.
        publish_acceleration: true

# Whether to broadcast the transformation over the /tf topic. Defaultsto true if unspecified.
        publish_tf: true

        print_diagnostics: true

        debug: false
        debug_out_file: "ekf-log.txt"

        print_diagnostics: true

# 1. Set the map_frame, odom_frame, and base_link frames to the appropriate frame names for your system.
#     1a. If your system does not have a map_frame, just remove it, and make sure "world_frame" is set to the value of odom_frame.
# 2. If you are fusing continuous position data such as wheel encoder odometry, visual odometry, or IMU data, set "world_frame"
#    to your odom_frame value. This is the default behavior for robot_localization's state estimation nodes.
# 3. If you are fusing global absolute position data that is subject to discrete jumps (e.g., GPS or position updates from landmark
#    observations) then:
#     3a. Set your "world_frame" to your map_frame value
#     3b. MAKE SURE something else is generating the odom->base_link transform. Note that this can even be another state estimation node
#         from robot_localization! However, that instance should *not* fuse the global data.
        # map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_footprint  # Defaults to "base_link" ifunspecified
        world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value ofodom_frame if unspecified

        imu0: /ouster/imu
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                        false,  false,  true,
                        false, false, false,
                        true,  true, true,
                        true,  true,  true]
        imu0_differential: false  # If using a real robot you might want to set this to true, since usually absolute measurements from real imu's are not very accurate
        imu0_relative: false
        imu0_queue_size: 10
        imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

        use_control: false


Here is the imu_sim node:
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu


class ImuPub(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Imu, '/ouster/imu', 10)
        timer_period = 0.1  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = Imu()
        msg.linear_acceleration.z = -9.80
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % str(msg))
        self.i += 1


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    pub = ImuPub()
    rclpy.spin(pub)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    pub.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

